# Dynamic interaction between parameters in Vega Lite?

Tags: javascript, vega-lite, vega, dynamic-variables

[Link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUAkgHZgYAe8AjADQgByEAthvCAFIREu0CCjA9miJQqABloARaCzggAHAHpKohQCZRqgMwhaAMQgBjAJYojUAJ6seOkAGU0ABwwAnREaz9nVxpYC+1QhJyKloGZlZbJhs+QWF4OUlpVkVKTTUNbT1DEzNLWQAhG3snV3dPbz8AkGJSCjgaeiYZEHyTFGiBIRF61USoZoB2JQA2dK0bfWNTC1YAYSLHFzcPL1k2fgALIhBfAF1aIibWSBgsDBF-EAcIZyYcOHwQQ-DZYqWyr1pkdGa+S1oAEZGEjwUDAhxobogW5gIz8Gz8BxQOFEe64EB-GzrLYgXa+fygZ7NMLcEDfTCsGxAkEIEDgyGsM4oDAGES0RHI-iovDsTikyKMGytFDtPF7WiMG4Aa1BIAsTlYDn4wLZcv4-BQyIc8Cgzkwl11nCwADNPIKHqBjSZ+qtwNA0IxcAByN6lFZO3YAAgAvN7Pa7luVxSAMEQDPxYUQAOayuqWowYFBgVhSfo2eXNfqMJW3dqXPLxxPJ2STHIzWgZ1hEfiMYGoHb4oA) to minimal working example. Here is the part of the code I am dealing with:

```
"params": [
    {
      "name": "Supervisor",
      "value": "Amy",
      "bind": {"input": "radio", "options": ["Amy", "John"]}
    },
    {
      "name": "Name",
      "value": "",
      "bind": {"input": "select", "options": ["Jane", "Sam", "Bill"]}
    }
```

I would like the input for `Name` to be conditional based on the current value of `Supervisor`:
If `Supervisor == Amy`, display `"Jane", "Sam"` under `"Name"`. If `Supervisor == John`, display `"Bill"` under `"Name"`.

I tried to use the Vega Lite "condition" property, but it works only within `mark` channels. This was my idea:

```
"params": [
    {
      "name": "Supervisor",
      "value": "Amy",
      "bind": {"input": "radio", "options": ["Amy", "John"]}
    },
    {
      "name": "Name",
      "value": "",
      "bind": {"input": "select", 
      "options": 
      [
        "condition": 
          [
            {
              "test": "Supervisor === 'Amy'", 
              "value": ["Jane", "Sam"]
            },
            {
              "test": "Supervisor === 'John'", 
              "value": ["Bill"]
            }
          ]
    }
  ]
```

I then tried exchanging `params` for `signals`, but found that  `"transform": [{"filter": "datum['Supervisor'] == Supervisor"}]` would not work when Supervisor is not a parameter.

Will I have to progress to Vega for this functionality?

Comment: Can you use javascript instead of the built in parameters?
I often use a devextreme datagrid which supports cascading drop-down filters. 
So you could apply one or more filters and your charts would update automatically.
Example: https://apbreports.com/dashboards/vega_lite_2023-03-15/html/TOPN.html